# Receive value by key

Tags: javascript, typescript

How could I get from the value of `key:text`. The problem is that `txt[key].key` gives an error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

What is the best option to get the value of `key === text`

```
const txt = [
  { key: 'topic', type: 'STRING', value: 'test' },
  { key: 'key', type: 'STRING', value: '007' },
  {
    key: 'text',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: 'I want to get this text'
  }
]

Object.keys(txt).forEach(key => {
    if (txt[key].key === 'text') {
        console.log("Found.");
    }
});

// What I also tried

Object.keys(txt).forEach((key: string | number) => {
    if (txt[key].key === 'text') {
        console.log("Found.");
    }
});
```

What I want

```
I want to get this text
```

Comment: Did you define the `type` of this object anywhere?

Comment: @Kokodoko I do not think so.

Comment: There is a better way probably to do, but this should work:         console.log(txt.filter(item => item?.key == "text").flatMap(item => item.value))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an improvement to [Vega's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73150387/13779664):

You can use the find function instead of the filter function as find returns only the first match and that's what you want it seems

```
const txt = [{
    key: 'topic',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: 'test'
  },
  {
    key: 'key',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: '007'
  },
  {
    key: 'text',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: 'I want to get this text'
  }
]

const element = txt.find(t => t.key === 'text')

console.log(element.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you define your key as "string | number"? It is only string, isn't it ? But there is also another approach to your problem.
You can simply use [JavaScript filter() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const txt = [{
    key: 'topic',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: 'test'
  },
  {
    key: 'key',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: '007'
  },
  {
    key: 'text',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: 'I want to get this text'
  }
]

const textArray = txt.filter(t => t.key === 'text')

console.log(textArray);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. What I got is `Object is possibly 'null'.` for `t`. `txt` is a variable. I check if it is null with `if(txt != null) {your code}`.

Comment: You can just type your txt variable. `const txt: {key: string; type: string; value: string;}` or `[key: string]: string`. Then `t` will be typed implicitly and the warning should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about types, this is how you access the item value.

The correct ways could be

```
console.log(txt.filter(item => item?.key == "text")[0].value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers utilize filter method, below is the version using txt.forEach()

```js
const txt = [
  { key: 'topic', type: 'STRING', value: 'test' },
  { key: 'key', type: 'STRING', value: '007' },
  {
    key: 'text',
    type: 'STRING',
    value: 'I want to get this text'
  }
]

txt.forEach(element => {
  if(element["key"] === "text")
  {
    console.log(element["value"]);
  }
});
```